# Exclude spring boot JPA repository for code generation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have a spring boot 3 project that uses multiple data sources for different JPA repositories, and on the rest controllers I use openapi generators such that I can create clients etc. for the controllers.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to correctly configure my profile that I use for the openapi generation, such that my datasources are ignored and the application not trying to connect to the databases, that are not available at this time.

I have implemented the multiple data sources using this approach [Configure and Use Multiple DataSources in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources)

And for normal configuration I would exclude the auto configure of JDBC, orm, JPA etc. as such:

```
spring:
    autoconfigure:
        exclude:
          - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
          - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
          - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
```

But this still don't work as I get an error due to the creation of `entityManagerFactoryRef` in the `EnableJpaRepositories`.

Is there any way to ensure that I can start my spring boot application, without access to any databases, during build time?